# Programmatic validation + submit in an Acrobat PDF form

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, acrobat, adobe-javascript

Upon pressing the "submit" button of my PDF form, I'd like to do something (set a field to readonly) conditionally on the success of the form validation and submission processes:

```
if (form.isValid()) {
    submitForm(...);
    if (form.wasSubmittedSuccessfully()) {
        //doSomething();
    }
}
```

I'd like to know if there's an easy way to implement `form.isValid()` (i.e. verify that all required fields are non-null and correctly formatted) and `form.wasSubmittedSuccessfully()` above.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need to embed some Javascript (validation function) in your PDFs and attach the function to click event of a submit button.

[JavaScript™ for Acrobat® API Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) contains information about anything in Javascript supported by Adobe products. Some of the methods and properties are also supported by 3rd-part 
y viewers.

You can embed Javascript in a PDF using Acrobat Professional and a number of 3rd-party tools and libraries.

EDIT:

Here are couple of links that might help you to get started:

- [Example Acrobat JavaScripts](http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/article.asp?ContentID=6828)
- [JavaScript - Introduction to Development with Examples](http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/article.asp?ContentID=6575)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I am aware of course that some JS is involved, and I am looking for a quick code snippet, as the manual you're referring to is rather bulky, and my searches in it didn't yet yield any result..

Comment: @cjauvin what language / platform do you plan to use for the task?

Comment: Which language beside JS could I use for this (with Acrobat Pro X)? I'm not sure I understand your question, as well as the fact that my (perfectly honest and valid) question is now worth a negative value! It would be very useful for me to know why..

Comment: @cjauvin I've updated my answer with couple of potentially useful links. As for downvote, I don't know why someone decided that your question is not good enough.